# How to detect a person when he/she is near an object?

Tags: python, object-detection

I have a python script which will open my webcam and detect object using yolov3.

But when the person is near a specific object (for example a rack), I need to identify the person and compute how long the person spent in that place.

What should I do in order to make it work?

Comment: Could you post some of your code? It's hard to recommend something without seeing the methods you are using.

Answer (score 1):

using yolov3 is a bit tough, so I suggest you to use a more easy and clean module, the opencv module. It's not compulsory which module you use, but for better experience, use OpenCV.

**First install it :**
`pip install opencv-python`

OpenCV already contains many pre-trained classifiers for face, eyes, smiles, etc.. I will be using classifier. You can experiment with other classifiers as well.
You need to download the trained classifier XML file (haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml), which is available in OpenCv’s GitHub repository. Save it to your working location.
In the below code, I am converting the colourful image to black and white image.

**THE CODE :**

```
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

We can do it for videos too because videos are actually many frames per second, so we can take it as image, so for videos you can use the following **CODE:**

```
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam. 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# now we will use an infinitive loop to read for each frames per second
while True:
    
    _, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)

    # Stop if escape key is pressed

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

But if you still want to use yolov3, then go through the documentation, but again, you might probably lacking some skills so use OpenCV for getting experience.
**GOOD LUCK!!**